# c# Add HelpButton to a MDI child form at run time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i'd like the following code to work (where this. is a MDI child form)

```
this.HelpButton = true;
this.HelpButtonClicked += HandleHelpButtonClicked;
this.Refresh();
```

this code is being called after the mdi child form is displayed.

I wonder if i need to find some way of redrawing the title bar?

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbutton.aspx):

> The value of the HelpButton property is ignored if the Maximize or Minimize buttons are shown.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to add a toolbar or menu and put a help button on it. Then you can handle the click of that button.